# Flutter: child of ConstrainedBox donot display

Tags: flutter

When I set maxHeight of BoxConstraints to 100 or other value, the Image can display. But when I set maxHeight to 0, the Image is not visible. How to make it visible?

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('world'),
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),),
            Image.network(
                'http://cdn.nanxiongnandi.com/bing/KingfishersTaipei_ZH-CN13235647615_1366x768.jpg'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkvHl.png)

Comment: Why would it be visible if it has a height of 0?

Comment: Text and IconButton are visible, but Image is not visible, I do not why

Comment: I want Image visible if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I see that your image has the problem to load. Check the below code with maxHeight to 100. It is working

```
 return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 100),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('world'),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
          ),
          Image.network(
              'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/website/master/src/_includes/code/layout/lakes/images/lake.jpg'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image]

Comment: You are right. But when maxHeight is 0, how to make it visible?

Comment: You will have to allow max-height should be greater than 0. Otherwise, it will not visible. Check the above code which i posted for the answer

Comment: Why is Text visible? It is strange.

Comment: because you have multiple children in Row widget.  Text('world'),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
          ),